# Get the Http response status using 'httpClient(postRequest,Handler)' method

Tags: java, httpresponse

While looking around I've found this method:

```
String JSONResult = httpclient.execute(request,handler); 
//Request is an HttpPost object, handler is a ResponseHandler<String>
```

This method made things much easier for me, i can now get the JSON response coming from my server without all these `inputStream` `BuffredReader`.... story.

But the problem is that i can't get the `HttpResponse Status` now like if I'd Used :

```
HttpResponse Response = httpclient.execute(request);
Response.getStatusLine();
```

Is there any way to use the first method, and still be able to get the the `Response status`?

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there any way to use the first method, and still be able to get the the Response status?*

No.

Here's what you do

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
ResponseHandler handler = ...;
String JSONResult = handler.handleResponse(response);
StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
```

Now you have access to the status from the `HttpResponse` object and are able to process the response with a `ResponseHandler` to get the json result. The point of the different methods is that you don't really care about the status, only the handled response.

Comment: Great it's working very fine, one last thing before accepting your answer, why do people do that the hard way, with input stream buffered reader, but not this way?

Comment: @HossamOukli Either they are unaware of `ResponseHandler` or they are implementing a different interface that expects an `InputStream`. For example, you could use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to get JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the status and use `EntityUtils` save messing around with input streams and buffered readers.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Comment: While debugging I'm not sure why i get The `source not found` with the `BasicHttpEntity.class`